# Evaluating a limit containing a variable inside a summation and of a summations bound

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

This is the formula I derived for the chance of rolling an n-sided die n times, and landing on one an odd amount of times (do correct me if I'm wrong, though):
$$C(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}\binom{n}{2k-1}\frac{(n-1)^{n-2k+1}}{n^n}$$
My question is how to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}C(n)$, if a closed form exists. Since $C(n)$ has its variable inside both the summation, and the summations bound, I wouldn't know how to go about this. I've tried using simplifications, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

After simplification, this gives
$$C(2n)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{2 n}$$
$$C(2n+1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2 n-1}{2 n+1}\right)^{2 n+1}$$

Comment: Can you clarify why those are true? Sorry but I don't think I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_{i, n}$ be $1$ if the result of the $i-$th roll is $1$ and $0$ otherwise. You are looking for the following probability:

$$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,n} \text{ is odd}\right] = P\left[B\left(n, \frac1n\right)\text{ is odd}\right] \underset {n\to \infty}\to P\left[Poi\left(1\right)\text{ is odd}\right] = \frac 12\left(1 - \frac1e\right).$$